# Solving a Multiple integral using Spherical coordinate system

Tags: calculus, integration

I was asked to solve the next integral:

$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} \ \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}} x^2+y^2+z^2 \,dzdxdy$

I want to use the spherical coordinate system but I can't seem to find one of the angles. Any help will be gladly accepted!

Comment: Write down your solution and point out where specifically you need help.

Comment: I'm sorry English is not my first language
I found out that the radius r is between 0 and 18^0.5
One of the angles is from 0 to pi/2
and the other angle is from  something i don't quite know to pi

Answer (score 0):

We have $x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi, y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi, z=r\cos\theta$ with $r\geq0, 0\leq\theta\leq\pi, 0\leq\phi\leq2\pi$.

From $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq z\leq\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}$ we have $r\sin\theta\leq r\cos\theta\leq \sqrt{18-r^2\sin^2\theta}$. This implies $\sin\theta\leq \cos\theta$ or $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $r^2\leq18$, thus $r\leq3\sqrt{2}$.

From $0\leq x\leq\sqrt{9-y^2}$ we have $0\leq r\sin\theta\cos\phi$ and $r^2\sin^2\theta\leq9$. Thus $\cos\phi\geq0$,  or $0\leq \phi\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$ (Here $r \leq 3\sqrt{2}$ is a stronger condition than $r\leq \frac{3}{\sin\theta}$).

From $0\leq y\leq3$ we obtain that only $0\leq \phi\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ is possible.

Since $dxdydz=r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$ the value of integral is

$\int_{0}^{3\sqrt{2}}r^4dr\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin\theta d\theta \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d\phi=\frac{486(\sqrt{2}-1)}{5}\pi$.